# How to use an AWS cli command in a Terraform external data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

If I run the following command on its own I get the expected result -

This :

```
aws cloudfront list-cloud-front-origin-access-identities | jq -r ' .CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityList.Items[] | select(.Comment == "Created for Nackle Shared CF in pprd").Id'
```

Returns this:

```
E1P6ZIBDB6I6FZ
```

How can I use the Terraform external data source to get the same result?

I tried this :

```
data "external" "json" {
program = ["sh", "-c", "aws cloudfront list-cloud-front-origin-access-identities | jq -r ' .CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityList.Items[] | select(.Comment == "Created for Nackle Shared CF in pprd").Id'"] 
}

output "map" {
value = ["${values(data.external.json.result)}"] 
}
```

But it returns this error when I run the Terraform apply -

```
Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.
```

I assume when it is written properly the "value" will be E1P6ZIBDB6I6FZ ?

How do I use the value as a variable in another part of my terraform?

Is there a different way to approach this?

I am new to Terraform and have never played with external data sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The json parsing ability of external data source is very limited. It should be (escape quote and return new json):

```
data "external" "json" {
program = ["sh", "-c", "aws cloudfront list-cloud-front-origin-access-identities | jq -r ' .CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityList.Items[] | select(.Comment == \"Created for Nackle Shared CF in pprd\") |  {id: .Id}'"] 
}
```

Then you access the Id as:

```
data.external.json.result["id"]
```

Comment: It works great. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @ErnieAndBert Please also consider an upvote to show appreciation towards an accepted answer.

Comment: @Marcin In case of using TF Cloud remote execution do I need to install aws cli on an agent before?